# Curving a line chart inside a curved arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, nvd3.js, graph-visualization

I am new to D3 and learning it. I am trying to build a curved line chart. That is i want to bend the line chart inside a half circle. It will be helpful if any one can tell me how to approach this in D3.

Something as shown in the link below:
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jianzhao/snapshots/kronominer.jpg

Comment: can you mock-up an example?  even in free hand would be helpful.

Comment: This link shows the image of kronominer. I am trying to build the line graph within an arc similar to shown in the image.http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jianzhao/snapshots/kronominer.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to drawing a line chart in Cartesian coordinates, but using D3's radial line function rather than the regular line function.  Your line's x coordinate becomes the angle, and the y coordinate the radial distance.

```
var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .radius(function(d){return r(d.y);})
    .angle(function(d){return theta(d.x);});
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajlund/osz5khm3/) shows a simple example with sample data.

Comment: This is what i was exactly looking for. Thanks angus i have implemented this and the other thing that i tried was to normailize all points to a length inside an arc and then plot it. RADIAL_X
[RADIAL_NORMALISED_LENGTH] * COS([RADIAL_ANGLE])

RADIAL_Y
[RADIAL_NORMALISED_LENGTH] * SIN([RADIAL_ANGLE])

Answer (score 0):

Its called a Sunbusrt Chart, here is a few links to get you started.

> - Sunburst Partition By Mike Bostock [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423)
> - Sequences sunburst By kerryrodden [here](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Shabeer,Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking for more like something shown in the link below.I am trying to build the line graph within an arc similar to shown in the image. cs.toronto.edu/~jianzhao/snapshots/kronominer.jpg