# line chart inside arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, nvd3.js

Hi I am new to D3 and i'm working on the visualization of time series.I would like to develop visualization prototype . It will be helpful if somebody has an advanced example of curved line chart inside arc like this.
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jianzhao/papers/kronominer.pdf
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **d3.svg.line.radial** function for this,

```
d3.svg.line.radial().radius(function(d){}).angle(function(d){});
```

Refer [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437093/curving-a-line-chart-inside-a-curved-arc?rq=1) and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajlund/osz5khm3/) for more help. Radar charts are also implemented using this function to draw [curved line graphs](http://bl.ocks.org/jeffthink/1630683).

Comment: Thanks Nithin CV Poyyil